# Prove that a sequence of steps terminates

Tags: coq, lambda-calculus

I have a small system that rewrites lambda terms.  It has the usual (three) deterministic call-by-value rewrite rules. I have not listed them here.

The rewrites are modelled as `Step`s from one `Term` to another.  I have also the `StarStep` relation between *reachable* terms, where the latter can be produced from the first by zero or more rewrite steps.

I now want to show that the rewrites terminate (either with a value, or stuck).  I have stripped out the details, because I don't think they matter here, but I can add more details if needed.

Here is the code (or [here](https://x80.org/collacoq/gahaboravi.coq) in *CollaCoq* in the browser):

```
Variable Term: Type.
Variable Step: Term -> Term -> Prop.
Inductive StarStep: Term -> Term -> Prop :=
| StepNone : forall t, StarStep t t
| StepOne  : forall t t', Step t t' -> forall t'', StarStep t' t'' -> StarStep t t''.

Goal forall t : Term,
    ~ (forall t', StarStep t t' -> exists t'', Step t' t'') ->
    exists t', StarStep t t' /\ forall t'', ~ Step t' t''.
```

So I want to show

> IF it is NOT the case that *"from all reachable states it is possible
>   another step"* THEN there exists a state  `t'` that is reachable from `t`
>   such that it is not possible to take a step from it.

I am stuck on how to proceed.  Do I need more info, i.e. induction or destructing (= case analysis of) `t`? And how can I use the info in the hypothesis when it is negated?

EDIT:  [Here are more details about `Term` and `Step`](https://x80.org/collacoq/exipigipem.coq)

Comment: Note that you can `Comments "pkgs: coq-reals".` at the beginning of your collacoq file and it will load many more Coq libraries so you don't have to reimplement string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is an instance of *classical* reasoning.
The statement resembles the following proposition, which is not provable in the constructive setting:

```
Goal forall (A : Type) (P : A -> Prop),
  ~ (forall x, P x) -> exists x, ~ P x.
```

because the knowledge that "it is not true that forall ..." doesn't yield  an object which you need to prove the existence of something.

Here is a possible solution using the laws of classical logic:

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.Classical_Pred_Type.
Require Import Coq.Logic.Classical_Prop.

Goal forall t : Term,
    ~ (forall t', StarStep t t' -> exists t'', Step t' t'') ->
    exists t', StarStep t t' /\ forall t'', ~ Step t' t''.
Proof.
  intros t H.
  apply not_all_ex_not in H.
  destruct H as [tt H].
  apply imply_to_and in H.
  firstorder.
Qed.
```

Actually, we don't even need to know anything about `StarStep`, because the following abstract version of the previous proposition is valid in classical logic (the proof remains the same):

```
Goal forall (A : Type) (P Q : A -> Prop),
    ~ (forall s, Q s -> exists t, P t) ->
    exists s, Q s /\ forall t, ~ P t.
```